# How to reduce the borders around subplots in matlab?

Tags: matlab, subplot

In matlab, an inordinate amount of space is wasted around subplots.  For example, in this example:

```
t = 0:0.001:2*pi+0.001;
figure(2);
for i = 1 : 25;
    subplot(5,5,i);
    plot(t, sin(i*t));
    axis off
end
```

[image: Example of wasted white space in subplots]

over 50% of the space on the figure is wasted as "blank"  I'd like to shrink that blank space down, but have been unsuccessful to identify a mechanism to do so.  Thoughts?

Comment: Here is a list of other possible solutions: [tight subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27991-tight-subplot), [jointfig.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/304-jointfig-m), [Some Matlab tricks for making figures](http://nibot-lab.livejournal.com/73290.html), [Useful little utility](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/5706e8dfbb4a418/f5154f1df6efaff4), [Reduce Grey Space around Images in a Figure](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/6254-reduce-grey-space-around-images-in-a-figure)

Comment: Note:  As of 2019b, Mathworks has solved this problem with the tiledlayout command.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [`subaxis`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696) function on the File Exchange allows you to specify margins for subplots.

Example usage:

```
t = 0:0.001:2*pi+0.001;
figure(2);
for i = 1 : 25;
    subaxis(5,5,i, 'Spacing', 0.03, 'Padding', 0, 'Margin', 0);
    plot(t, sin(i*t));
    axis tight
    axis off
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can position them yourself (or programatically) using

```
subplot('Position',[left bottom width height]);
```

By default, the coordinates are normalized. So a position
of [0.1 0.1 0.5 0.5] will start at 10% of the way in
from the lower left corner, and will have a width equal
to half the figure width, and a height equal to half the
figure height.

See the accepted answer for a built-in solution to margins and padding.

Answer (score 5):

Try to reduce the default values in the hidden axes `LooseInsets` property, as described in http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/axes-looseinset-property/

For example:

```
set(gca, 'LooseInset', get(gca,'TightInset'))
```

Comment: At least in my example, this does nothing on 2011a.

Comment: the extra space is taken up by the hidden X & Y axes tick labels, and I do not believe they can be eliminated. But you can improve the situation as follows:

  `figure(2); for i = 1 : 25; hax=axes(); plot(t, sin(i*t)); axis tight; axis off; rowIdx=fix((i-1)/5); colIdx=mod(i-1,5); newPos=[.2*colIdx,0.8-.2*rowIdx,.2,.2]; set(gca,'outer',newPos), end`

Comment: Does LooseInset work with subplots ?