# Printing Matlab plot: how to reduce grey borders?

Tags: matlab, plot, border

This block creates two subplots and then prints the resulting plot into a TIF file:

```
h = figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(rand(5,1));
legend('1st legend');
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(rand(5,1));
legend('2nd legend');
drawnow;
print(h,'-dtiff','-r300','plot.tif');
```

The resulting plot has large grey borders. I want them to be as small as possible and the subplots to be as detailed as possible. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685092/how-to-reduce-the-borders-around-subplots-in-matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the set subplot position. I wrote down some numbers, but they are not optimized. I encourage you to play with the numbers to fill the figure as you want.

```
h = figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(rand(5,1));
legend('1st legend');
set(subplot(1, 2, 1), 'Position', [0.07, 0.07, 0.40, 0.90])
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(rand(5,1));
legend('2nd legend');
set(subplot(1, 2, 2), 'Position', [0.50, 0.07, 0.40, 0.90])
drawnow;
```