# Displaying images is Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I want To write a Matlab function that can display one single image, multiple images (i.e. cell arrays, vector, matrices) of images so that I don't need to worry about writing 'plots', 'subplots', and other complicated Matlab mechanisms each time I run my program with new inputs. That is also one of my requirements in my project.

The following source code has several problems:

1. it can't show only one image
2. occasionally it doesn't preserve the original aspect ratio of images
3. resizing the window to a smaller size drastically reduces the size of the images on display

**How can I fix these issues?**

---

*Source Code*

```
function draw_images(image_list)    
    d = size(image_list);
    l = length(d);

    figure;
    hold all
    colormap(gray(256));  

    % vector or cell-array
    if(l==2)
        N = length(image_list);
        [m, n] = factor_out(N);

        % images may be of differenet dimensions
        if(iscell(image_list))    
            for k=1:N
                h = subplot(m,n,k);
                image(image_list{k},'Parent',h);
                set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
            end
        % must be of same dimension
        elseif(isvector(image_list))
            for k=1:N
                h = subplot(m,n,k);
                image(image_list(k),'Parent',h);
                set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
            end
        end
    % 3D matrix of images (!!!)
    elseif(l==3)
        N = d(3) ;
        [m, n] = factor_out(N);
        for k=1:N
            I = image_list(:,:,k);
            subplot(m,n,k);
            imshow(I);
            set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
        end  
    end     
    hold off

function [m, n] = factor_out(input_number)
    sqrtt = ceil(sqrt(input_number));    
    m = sqrtt;
    n = sqrtt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no a built-in solution similar to `pyplot.tight-layout()` in python. However, there exist several solutions written by several authors. I would prefer the function called [subtightplot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39664-subtightplot)

There is also a discussion regarding this question at Stackoverflow called [How to reduce the borders around subplots in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685092/how-to-reduce-the-borders-around-subplots-in-matlab)